# Git rebase not applying commits at merge-base

Tags: git

I have a git history like this:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - G    <- Master
          \
            H - I - J        <- Feature
```

I want to update the **feature** branch with changes from the **master** branch. From the **feature** branch, I run `git rebase master` expecting it to look like this:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - G               <- Master
                         \
                          H - I - J     <- Feature
```

Except I get this:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - G                 <- Master
          \
            H - I - J - D - E - F - G     <- Feature
```

So, changes from the master branch are being applied on TOP of my feature branch (commit J), instead of at the point of diversion (commit C)

I know I'm not doing this right... and I cant seem to google my question properly. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Is there a repo people can inspect to see by chance?

Comment: That sounds like you are either running the operations on the wrong branches (checkout master, rebase feature) or the branch pointers are not at the right position. Check your starting point and the other branch before running rebase.

Comment: @aug unfortunately, no. I essentially want my feature branch to look like it starts from commit G on master... if that helps

Comment: @eftshift0 thats the thing... I dont think git knows where the starting point is... even though commit C is the nearest common ancestor of both branches. Git should be starting from there right?

Comment: The starting point of a branch? Well, git can certainly know what the last point common to both branches is (check `git merge-base`) but that is not necessarily the starting point. You might have merges in between and then the very original starting point gets lots. That's information that git does not care about so it'snot held as metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mean to do `git rebase --onto master` while in feature branch.

You could also temporarily set upstream to master, then a simple `git rebase` should do the trick.